# Pandas DataFrame Statisitics Tracking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to output a count for the number of times the data is >11 for one column in my dataframe. I have tried using df2['LOC6'].value_counts() before, but I do not think it is applicable in this situation. LOC6 is the name of the column.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(df2['LOC6'] > 11).sum()
```

Comment: worked perfectly! Thanks! Didn't realize it was such a simple solution...

Comment: what if you were looking to find the count across the whole dataframe?

Comment: `(df2 > 11).sum()`